# Redirigir a otra url en funcion del referer

Tags: javascript, html, script

Tengo este código en el index.php de un dominio:

```
    <?php           

    if (isset($_POST["redirect"])) {    

        $hash = $_POST["redirect"];

        if ($hash !== "") {     

            $origen = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
            $destino = "";

                 if($origen == 'http://www.example.net/test') $destino = 'https://www.test.com/ad';     
            else if($origen == 'http://www.example.net/test2') $destino = 'https://test.com/ad2';                

            if($destino != "")
            {

             echo "<script>window.location.href = '".$destino."';</script>";
            } 
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto, ya que si el usuario entra desde uno de los referers especificados, va hacía la URL especificada en función del referer de entrada, pero si el usuario entra desde cualquier otro referer que no sea ninguno de los mencionados (o que el referer sea blank) el usuario se queda en esa misma URL (de este index.php) en blanco. Como puedo hacer para que el usuario vaya a una URL concreta (y no se quede en el index actual) para todos los demás casos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php           

if (isset($_POST["redirect"])) {    

    $hash = $_POST["redirect"];

    if ($hash !== "") {     

        $origen = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
        $destino = "";

        if($origen == 'http://www.example.net/test') $destino = 'https://www.test.com/ad';     
        else if($origen == 'http://www.example.net/test2') $destino = 'https://test.com/ad2';  
        else{
             $destino = "otra url"
        }              

        if($destino != "")
        {

           header("Location: $destino")
        } 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola, ten cuidado, las respuestas que solo tienen código y ninguna explicación son consideradas de baja calidad

Comment: Hola Mario Garcia, gracias por tu aporte, si bien esto puede responder a la pregunta considera agregar una descripción de como tu código resuelve el problema del autor. Para mas información puedes revisar [answer]

Answer (score 1):

Solo agrega un nuevo `else` a tu bloque condicional con la URL que usaras por defecto.

```
    ...

    if($origen == 'http://www.example.net/test') { 
        $destino = 'https://www.test.com/ad';
    } else if($origen == 'http://www.example.net/test2') { 
        $destino = 'https://test.com/ad2';                
    } else { 
        $destino = 'http://la-otra-url.com';                
    }

    ...
```